# How to create a serializer which return an array of hash without key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers

I need to create a structure like that using the active_model_serializers gem

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "code": "code",
      "name": "name"
    },
    {
      "code": "code",
      "name": "name"
    },
    {
      "code": "code",
      "name": "name"
    },
    {
      "code": "code",
      "name": "name"
    }
  ]
}
```

Categories refers to a PORO virtus:

```
module Api
  module Bitsky
    class MarketStructure
      include Virtus.model

      attribute :department_name, String
      attribute :department_code, Integer
      attribute :department_value, String
      attribute :sector_name, String
      attribute :sector_code, Integer
      attribute :sector_value, String
      attribute :family_name, String
      attribute :family_code, Integer
      attribute :family_value, String
      attribute :sub_family_name, String
      attribute :sub_family_code, Integer
      attribute :sub_family_value, String
    end
  end
end
```

I've code this serializer to try to create that hash. It worked, however the result was not what I expected.

```
module Api
  module Bitsky
    class MarketStructure< ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :categories

     def categories
       *** some operation ***
     end
    end
  end
end
```

Result

```
{
  "categories": {
    "categories": [
      {
        "code": "code",
        "name": "name"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I write a serializer which return only a Hash Array without this key "categories" ?

Answer (score 3):

You should be doing something like this

```
@categories.as_json(root: false)
```

or

```
render json: @categories, root: false
```